# Getting AJAX content with Python Selenium and PhantomJS

Tags: python, selenium, web-crawler, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I am writing a crawler that needs to wait for all AJAX loaded HTML content and then extract any anchor tags from them. When I call webdriver.get(URL), I'm not sure that it actually waits for some of the AJAX content to be added to the DOM. I can do some sort of implicit or explicit wait as defined in the docs [here](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits). However, even after waiting, webdriver.page_source is the same as it was before waiting. Is there anyway I can get the AJAX content into the webdriver.page_source after waiting, so that I can analyze the asynchronously inserted content?

Comment: `webdriver.page_source is the same as it was before waiting` -> This almost certainly means you aren't using the explicit wait correctly. If the element is in the DOM, you will see it in the page source. I'll bet that your element path isn't narrow enough, and is picking up something else in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

I would check the existence of a certain element you know to be loaded asynchronously in the HTML DOM.